# ¿Cómo hacer que un lector de huella identifique sin tener que usar un botón?

Tags: java

Necesito hacer que cuando ponga el dedo en el lector de huella si se encuentra registrado en la base de datos, lo identifique automáticamente sin necesidad de un botón

Este seria el boton identificar

```
    private void BtnIdentificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            identificarHuella();
            Reclutador.clear();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(CapturarHuella.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Aqui es donde el lector funciona, quisiera que ocurra lo mismo que pasa con el
.addSensorListener

```
protected void Iniciar(){


        Lector.addSensorListener(new DPFPSensorAdapter(){
        @Override public void fingerTouched(final DPFPSensorEvent e){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {
        EnviarTexto("El dedo ha sido colocado sobre el lector de huella");
        }});}
        @Override public void fingerGone(final DPFPSensorEvent e){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {
        EnviarTexto("El dedo ha sido quitado del lector de huella");
        }});}
        });

    }
```

Y aqui el metodo identificarHuella

```
public void identificarHuella() throws IOException{
        try{
            Connection c = con.conectar();

            PreparedStatement identificarStmt = c.prepareStatement("SELECT huenombre,huehuella FROM somhue");
            ResultSet rs = identificarStmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){

                byte templateBuffer[] = rs.getBytes("huehuella");
                String nombre = rs.getString("huenombre");

                DPFPTemplate referenceTemplate = DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory().createTemplate(templateBuffer);

                setTemplate(referenceTemplate);

                DPFPVerificationResult result = Verificador.verify(featuresverificacion, getTemplate());

                if(result.isVerified()){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La huella capturada es de "+nombre,"Verificacion de huella", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
            }

            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "No existe ningun registro que coincida con la huella","Verificacion de huella",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            setTemplate(null);
        }catch (SQLException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al identificar la huella dactilar"+e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            con.desconectar();
        }
    }
```

Si necesitan más detalles del codigo les puedo pasar el repositorio que tengo en github.
Al principio pensé que era agregando el .addSensorListener dentro del metodo identificarHuella(), pero no me dio, si tienen alguna idea de cómo debería realizar lo que pregunto, agradecería su ayuda, gracias.

Buenas, después de un tiempo llegue a una solución, sí me identifica sin la necesidad del botón pero me genera un error al querer guardar una nueva huella, de todos modos lo unico que se hace es agarrar el codigo dentro de **BtnIdentificar** y se mueve al **addSensorListener** de la siguiente manera:

```
protected void Iniciar(){
        Lector.addSensorListener(new DPFPSensorAdapter(){
        @Override public void fingerTouched(final DPFPSensorEvent e){SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {EnviarTexto("El dedo ha sido colocado sobre el lector de huella");
        }});}
        @Override public void fingerGone(final DPFPSensorEvent e){SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {public void run() {EnviarTexto("El dedo ha sido quitado del lector de huella");
        }});
        try{
            identificarHuella();
            Reclutador.clear();
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Logger.getLogger(CapturarHuella.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }
        });
    }
```

El error que se genera es que cada vez que ponga el dedo en el lector el **Reclutador** se va a reiniciar y por tanto no se va a guardar la plantilla para poder guardarla en la base de datos